# Running my flutter application on my virtual device

Tags: android, flutter

Following the steps in the flutter documentation, I was able to get to step 2 but I don't understand from that point I.e the step 3.
It says that

*Press the Settings button - a cog icon gear on the top right (now marked with a red or orange indicator) next to the DEBUG text box that reads No Configuration. Select flutter. And choose the debug configuration: To create your emulator if it is closed or to run the emulator or device that is now connected.*

The first time I tried it. I was able to select flutter but I think because of no internet connection, it did not work, but the second time, I only saw dart in the drop down
And again the only way I could get to the debug bar was by clicking on the debug tool that vs code has I.e on top of the extension icon.
Just vs code is opened, I have Android studio and flutter plugin and dart and also I have opened a virtual device pixel 5 I think.

Please someone should explain from that step down. 
This is also a screenshot of it.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just encountered the exact same issue. See screenshot for solution.

[image]